# Apache Cordova file-transfer to a django backend does not recognize the form data

Tags: python, django, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to send over a picture with the apache cordova file-transfer plugin to an django based backend. When I submit a picture via the file-transfer plugin in the backend, it doesn't recognize any of the parameters.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://127.0.0.1:8000/declare/"), win, fail, options);   
}
```

reqeust.FILES, request.POST, request.GET everything are empty dictionary. When I submit the url to a hookbin it seems to recognize everything though. What could be the problem why django keeps the request.FILES etc empty?

```
@csrf_exempt
def declare(request):
    me = User.objects.get(username='test')
    response = JsonResponse({'success': "ok"})
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
    return response
```

[image]

Comment: Honestly said I am not really sure what the issue was. The next day with the code virtually unchanged and it started working. I'm suspecting maybe something to do with a browser cache or compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cordova plugin uses chunked transfer by default.

```
chunkedMode: Whether to upload the data in chunked streaming mode. Defaults to true. (Boolean)
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

You may want to disable that or use a library to help chunk the upload on the server side like https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload

Comment: This is a good pointer to look into - but sadly when I inspected the http post with fiddler there was no chunked-mode active. Without doing really anything - i got the code to work, why it works, beats me.

Comment: Interesting...Because I didn't see anything other than this to be a reason why it wouldn't work